# XMLREADER Using PHP Get Named ATTRIBUTE Value

Tags: php, xmlreader

I am using XMLREADER with PHP to parse an XML file. I need to change the code to get the value of an attribute.

The XML:

```
<color eye="Green eyes" ethnicity="" hair="Brown Hair"/>
```

This is one method I've tried:

```
elseif($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'color') {
    $xml->read();
        if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ATTRIBUTE && $xml->name == 'eye') {
           $value4[] = $xml->value;
           $r4 = array_values($value4);
        }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
elseif($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'color') {
        $value4[] = $xml->getAttribute('eye');
        $r4 = array_values($value4);
    }
```

Using the code directly above I was able to get the 'eye' attribute value, but when I changed what's in () to 'hair' I didn't get anything.

Of the 2 methods I've tried, **which is the right one**, if either, and **what does it look like I am doing wrong**? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to parse big files? If not, simpleXML or DomDocument would be a lot easier

Comment: @AlexBarroso Yes, unfortunately I do need to parse big files